# How to change data points to circle using R on a mac (Quartz)

Tags: r, plot, quartz-graphics, markers

I would be very appreciative if someone could kindly advise me as to how I can inform R to change data points to circles instead of what appears to be underscores. I am using a Mac computer, and package is 'Quartz.'

For example:

```
quartz("Quartz", width=8, height=4, pointsize=16)
plot(dframe1$Group, dframe1$Lambda.max,type="p")
```

Image:

[image]

Comment: You have to earn some reputation before you're allowed to post images. For now, if you post a link to an image (on, say, imgur), someone with enough reputation can edit the image into your question.

Comment: The default for R points are circles. (and I just confirmed this with a run on a Mac.) So you have changed something in your setup. Don't ask multiple unrelated questions. Do some searching first (and do read the introductory SO pages) and then post separate questions.

Comment: This is a link to the plot in imgur    http://i.imgur.com/upka23P.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is more likely related to what you are plotting rather than the method of display.  If you try, for example, `plot(rnorm(10), rnorm(10), type="p")`, you'll see that you get circles.  I'm guessing that `dframe1$Group` is a factor.

Can you post a sample data set for reference?

So I'm using this as the dataset

```
dframe1 <- data.frame(Group=c("A1","A2", "B1", "B2"), Lambda.max=c(1,4,2,3))
```

which should be close enough.

This is a little tricky because R wants to do things a certain way for factors.  The approach I would recommend would be to draw the axes manually.

```
plot.default(dframe1$Group, dframe1$Lambda.max, type="p", axes=F)
axis(side=2)
axis(side=1, at=seq_along(dframe1$Group), labels=dframe1$Group)
```

edit: As requested, if you want a box around the plot as is fairly standard for R plots, you also have to manually add it

```
box()
```

Now the plot should look like this

[image: plot with box around it]

Comment: I am not sure how to format the data so that it is set up in two columns on here?

Comment: Edit your original post with the output of `dput(dframe1)`, or if that is too long, do a `dput(head(dframe1))` to get a relevant subset of the data.  That will allow your data to be easily imported into anyone else's session

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example is a great resource for this sort of thing

Comment: @KB2 Data as PDF can be terribly difficult to import, even if it looks pretty. Data from `dput()` may look ugly, but it's copy/pasteable and fully reproducible (it will preserve column classes).

Comment: Thank you very much for the help, would it be alright to keep this question open overnight? As I need to alter the graph a lot and I foresee myself not being able to do it...

Comment: @KB2: Up to you.  But I think general etiquette would be to close this question if you feel it has been answered adequately, and to post additional questions as necessary.  Remember that SO is a resource for the community as well, and too complex a question makes it hard for other users to get use out of this question.

Comment: @user295691 Ok. Here is so far what I have added to the graph: http://imgur.com/p3A59vk I was wondering how I could make the axes meet in the bottom left corner?